# Where do I add the .animate duration in this code snippet?

Tags: jquery

Jquery newb here.  I need to add a duration to this .animate, but because it is immediately followed by a scrollTop, I'm not quite sure where it goes.

```
<script>
$('#fund-selector').focus(function(){
     $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#gift-date").offset().top
    }, 2000);
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried your code ? It's working properly, check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sw5c6nrq/

```
$('#fund-selector').focus(function(){
     $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#gift-date").offset().top
    }, 2000);
})
```

Comment: Ahh..I'm a dummy.  I was thinking that the 2000 had something to do with the scrollTop.  Now realizing that it IS the duration!  Sorry for wasting your time, but thank you greatly for replying.